# Zero-Configuration Wide-Area Service Discovery through TCP - Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need to basically establish a remote TCP connection. From a Mac to an iPhone (on 3G, LTE, or another non-local network).

On my server side:

```
self.netService = [[NSNetService alloc]
initWithDomain:@"local." type:@"_myAppName._tcp."
name:chatRoomName port:self.port];
```

On my client side:

```
[netServiceBrowser searchForServicesOfType:@"_myAppName._tcp." inDomain:@"local."];
```

This works PERFECTLY on a local network. What I'm having trouble with is making this work on a remote level. I'm taking an wild guess here that all I have to change is inDomain:@"local." and initWithDomain:@"local." with something else.

I found [this](http://dns-sd.org). Interesting, but I'm still confused on implementation. Do I need to create a website with a hosting package, and I put inDomain:@"mywebsite.com"?

Any information is helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: When your iphone isn't on your local wifi, then it won't be on the  local domain. The address will be supplied by the wireless carrier. It could be possible to do some sort of dynamic dns on the iPhone... But really the iPhone should be the client and the desktop should be the server.

Comment: Yep! The iphone is the client and desktop is the server.

Comment: oh, then for a typical home setup you can set your router up with a dynamic DNS entry and forward whatever port you are interested in to the desktop... then by hitting the dynDNS name you will be hitting the "server"